# How to remove ( Delete ) the MGSE & Mate packages?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, mint

I've stuck when I installed the Mate package , not only I can't update my system more but also I can't open the software center and synaptic packet manager !

How can I remove the mate with all its details from my ubuntu machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have install MATE via the linux mint repository, then you will have upgraded many of the core ubuntu packages.  You will find it very difficult to "remove" MATE after this sort of upgrade.  I would suggest a restore from backup or just a complete reinstall...

However - if your concern is that software center/synaptic is not working then you can fix this as per the linked question.

N.B. IMHO the better way to experiment with MATE is per my answer here: [How do I install MATE (the desktop environment)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87040/how-to-install-mate-in-11-10-and-above/87567#87567)

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to I fix software center after installing the Linux Mint MATE desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81263/how-to-i-fix-software-center-after-installing-the-linux-mint-mate-desktop)

Comment: Can I get backup from the softwares ?

Comment: not sure I understand the question - if you are asking how do I do a disk image of the installation then use something like CloneZilla - you then will have a good backup that you can simply restore if your installation goes bad for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you guide me step by step and exactly ?

Comment: that really is another question you could ask... however there is an excellent step-by-step guide here:  http://geekyprojects.com/cloning/how-to-use-clonezilla-tutorial/

Comment: I shouldn't do it ( installing the mate ) , i won't install any shell in the future , How can I backup metasploit updates ?

Comment: ... personally I find it alot of fun... and often break my system.  Any data i have is on a separate external hard-drive that I can easily restore.  As to "how to I backup & restore metasploit updates" - I dont know the answer to this question.  Please ask it - maybe someone else does.

Comment: Hey man , I have to remove the mate ? is there any way ?

Comment: not really - its a one-way install.  If MATE is working for you, then leave it installed. Otherwise, try backing up your /home folder, reinstalling 11.10 and then putting back /home.  I dont know how well that will work, but have a drive-image backup just in-case...