# "ImportError: No module named Peppermint" after installing Ice from Peppermint

Tags: software-center

Software Center is not opening since I installed "Ice" software (used in Peppermint OS) from ppa:kendalltweaver/peppermint and i keep getting this error -

```
  $ software-center
    ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from debfile import DebFileApplication
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
        from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
        from softwarecenter.backend.channel import is_channel_available
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/channel.py", line 25, in <module>
        from softwarecenter.distro import get_distro
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
        distro_instance = _get_distro()
      File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 169, in _get_distro
        module = __import__(distro_id, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
    ImportError: No module named Peppermint
```

Comment: The PPA says "Prism has since been deprecated and a new application called Ice was developed to give similar functionality to Chromium specifically for LXDE. Peppermint uses the LXDE desktop environment" Are you using LXDE? Are you using Lubuntu? If not, you would probably be better to remove the PPA from your sources list.

Comment: i use unity, so i removed and rebooted, but still not working!

Comment: Connect to the Internet. Open a Terminal. Issue the command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade   ...Does that work or what error messages do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### diagnosis

Your error output looks remarkably similar to the linked question below.

In summary - by installing a non-ubuntu repository package you have overwritten the information that software center depends upon to inform it that it is running on ubuntu.

#### To correct this

Open a terminal window and change the *peppermint* release information with the defaults for *ubuntu*

N.B. copy and paste the following:

```
gksu gedit /etc/*release
```

and change everything in the file gedit brings up to:

*for 11.10*

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=Oneric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

*for 12.04*

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
```

Save and close the file.  Then copy and paste in a terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/*issue
```

and change to:

*11.10*

```
Ubuntu 11.10 \n \l
```

*12.04*

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS \n \l
```

Save and close.

---

Linked Question:

- [How to I fix software center after installing the Linux Mint MATE desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81263/how-to-i-fix-software-center-after-installing-the-linux-mint-mate-desktop)