# Running Peppermint's Ice on vanilla Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, webapps

I'm wondering how easy it would be to get [Ice](https://peppermintos.com/guide/ice/) (Peppermint's SSB Manager) running on Ubuntu 16.04? There are several websites (Evernote, Airdroid, Wunderlist) that run best from Chromium (and lack a good native client), but it would be even better if I could manage these with an app.

I found [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147279/importerror-no-module-named-peppermint-after-installing-ice-from-peppermint), which seems risky. Is there a way to implement this approach, without the negative consequences?

Alternatively, I downloaded Ice from [github](https://github.com/peppermintos/ice), but not sure what I have to do to run it--the README doesn't have much instruction.

(Note: I also found [this workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31427/how-do-i-put-a-web-application-on-the-launcher), but the info there seems outdated, since the ~/WebApps doesn't exist in 16.04; and having used Ice, the latter is more intuitive and user-friendly for managing these sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you just need to merge the `usr` directory from the repo with your own, I just did `sudo cp -dr usr/* /usr/` and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Hmm, you mean install Peppermint to a different partition, and then merging the directory?

Comment: No, cloning the Ice repo, theres a /usr/ directory in there

Comment: Ah, you mean git! Sorry, I'm a fairly new, let me give that a shot.