# Azure alternative for ubuntu

Tags: firefox, sync, cloud

The end user can store his/her Windows configurations to Azure, thus in case he formatted his PC Windows will restore the old configurations from the cloud. Is there any solution alternative for ubuntu OS?

PS

I'm using Mozilla Sync for my Firefox, it works fine and I wish to find a similar to it for whole operating system (I want my ubuntu configurations at work similar to my ubuntu at home)

Comment: I found a partial answer though [this post](http://www.thevarguy.com/2013/02/19/canonical-to-highlight-ubuntu-cloud-management-solutions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voila... [Ubuntu Software Center](https://launchpad.net/software-center) offers sync between computers. Thus I can sync between my computers exactly as I asked.

**PS**

For Mint user you've to modify two files as mentioned in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81263/how-to-i-fix-software-center-after-installing-the-linux-mint-mate-desktop) then you can use [Ubuntu Software Center](https://launchpad.net/software-center)... don't forget to change code name and release version as mentioned in `/etc/os-release`